# Under what conditions might this piece of code (From the React docs) fail, or rather actually trigger the final fallback condition?

Tags: reactjs, higher-order-components

The React docs have the following piece of code to extract the name of a component in an HOC ([function getDisplayName](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html#convention-wrap-the-display-name-for-easy-debugging:%7E:text=function%20getDisplayName)). See the getDisplayName implementation below.

```
function withSubscription(WrappedComponent) {
  class WithSubscription extends React.Component {/* ... */}
  WithSubscription.displayName = `WithSubscription(${getDisplayName(WrappedComponent)})`;
  return WithSubscription;
}

function getDisplayName(WrappedComponent) {
  return WrappedComponent.displayName || WrappedComponent.name || 'Component';
}
```

So in what cases will the function fail to get the component name ? and just return the generic string 'Component'. And if so, any ways to mitigate/handle such cases ?

Comment: Yeah, both `class`es and functions (functional components) have `.name`s. Wonder what edge cases they were considering for `'Component'`

Comment: @CertainPerformance yup! curious to know. would be awesome if a React core team member could take a look at it!

Comment: In cases where the parameter has neither a displayName nor name property. React is written using Flow typing; explicit types often mean more conservative code to guarantee that the return type is met. Look at the actual dev tools implementation, for example: https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/09a2c363a5175291ecdcbf7f39b0d165bc7da8ec/packages/react-devtools-shared/src/utils.js#L93-L96

Comment: Sure @jonrsharpe. Thanks for this. But I am more interested in knowing in what conditions this might happen, and how to mitigate them.

Comment: I mean to clarify @jonrsharpe, under what conditions "the parameter has neither a displayName nor name property" will happen , if I am using class components. And how could I mitigate them.

Comment: Under the conditions that something is passed that doesn't. Functions don't get to choose what's passed to them.

Comment: yes I understood that. I was talking more in terms of React domain specific. under what conditions the displayname and name won't be set on a React component instance ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So in what cases will the function fail to get the component name ?

If the given component neither has a `displayName` or is not a function or class e.g. when it was created with `React.forwardRef`.

> And if so, any ways to mitigate/handle such cases ?

There's currently no public API for this case. Subscribe to https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14319 for updates on this issue.